# Combine all the comments add up to an answer?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[thick, crunchy, fluffy corn flakes breading](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44678/thick-crunchy-fluffy-corn-flakes-breading) I'd like to consolidate the comments into one answer, but only a couple of the comments are mine. Would it be appropriate to use the wiki option for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community Wiki is for answers that you want or expect to have improved, edited, or generally maintained by the entire community, freely and without restriction - including users who just registered and have no reputation on the site - for better or for worse.

It's not a recommended or particularly useful way of *announcing* that different pieces of an answer *came from* other people. That's normal for any answer, if you think about it. If you're asserting that the answer is a reasonably complete answer and isn't an ongoing effort by the community (i.e. like a Wikipedia page) then it's your answer, not a community wiki.

Comment: Agreed, and if you want to feel good about it too, just note that none of those other people wrote an answer, they just wrote comments, while you're providing the thing we really want.

Comment: @Jefromi Excellent point. In this case someone else beat me to it (which of course is fine), but you're absolutely right. This issue has come up more than once. *If you can answer the question, answer it!*